# R-Studio Filtering Data

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I have this data table as model:

```
ID  PRODUCT_TYPE  OFFER INENTORY 
1    BED           Y      Y
2    TABLE         N      Y
3    MOUSE         Y      N
4    CELLPHONE     Y      Y
5    CAR           Y      Y
6    BED           N      N
7    TABLE         N      Y
8    MOUSE         Y      N
9    CELLPHONE     Y      Y
10    CAR          Y      Y
.....
```

I have to extract a sample of 50% of the total population and the sample must consist on appearance of the values ​​of the variables at least once (product_type == bed, cellphone, car, table, mouse, offer = Y, N, etc).

I used this to extract the sample:

```
subset1<- data2 %>% sample_frac(.5)
```

but I don't know how to integrate these conditions, can anyone help me with an advice?

Comment: Hello Adelina. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Nice job on your first question. It's helpful when one includes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a question to expedite receiving a relevant answer.  Did you intend to ask how to create a stratified random sample? If not, would you please edit your question and provide more details on the requirements for using product type, offer, and inventory to structure the sample?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear from the content of the original post whether the question it asks is *How does one generate a stratified random sample based on combinations of a set of grouping variables?* A stratified random sample is an appropriate approach in this situation because it ensures that each combination of grouping variables is proportionally represented in the sampled data frame.

### A tidyverse solution

Since the question does not include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we'll generate some data and illustrate how to split or group it and then randomly sample each of the subgroups.

To begin, we reset the seed for the random number generator and build a data frame containing 10,000 rows of products, where 50% of the products are on offer, and 70% are in inventory.

```
set.seed(1053807)
df <- data.frame(
     productType = rep(c("Bed","Mouse","Table","Cellphone","Laptop","Car","Chair","Blanket",
                          "Sofa","Bicycle"),1000),
     offer = ifelse(runif(10000) > .5,"Y","N"),
     inventory = ifelse(runif(10000) > .3,"Y","N"),
     price = rnorm(10000,200,10)
)
```

Given the three grouping variables in the original post, the `df` object contains 40 unique combinations of `productType`, `offer`, and `inventory`.

The original code attempts to use the `dplyr` package to sample the data. It was very close to a workable solution. To stratify the sample we use `group_by()` to group the data by split variables, and then use the `sample_frac()` function on the grouped data to generate the stratified sample.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
     group_by(productType,offer,inventory) %>%
     sample_frac(0.5) -> sampledData
```

#### Verifying results

A 50% sample from a 10,000 row data frame should have about 5,000 observations.

```
> nrow(sampledData)
[1] 5001
```

So far, so good.

We can then verify the results by counting numbers of rows in each stratum of the sample, and comparing them to the original counts for each subgroup in the input data frame.

```
# check results

originalCounts <- df %>% 
     group_by(productType,offer,inventory) %>%
     summarise(OriginalCount = n())

sampledData %>% 
     group_by(productType,offer,inventory) %>%
     summarise(SampledCount = n()) %>% 
     full_join(originalCounts,.) %>%
     mutate(SampledPct = round(SampledCount / OriginalCount * 100,2))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 40 x 6
# Groups:   productType, offer [20]
   productType offer inventory OriginalCount SampledCount SampledPct
   <chr>       <chr> <chr>             <int>        <int>      <dbl>
 1 Bed         N     N                   161           80       49.7
 2 Bed         N     Y                   371          186       50.1
 3 Bed         Y     N                   132           66       50  
 4 Bed         Y     Y                   336          168       50  
 5 Bicycle     N     N                   154           77       50  
 6 Bicycle     N     Y                   349          174       49.9
 7 Bicycle     Y     N                   147           74       50.3
 8 Bicycle     Y     Y                   350          175       50  
 9 Blanket     N     N                   134           67       50  
10 Blanket     N     Y                   349          174       49.9
# … with 30 more rows
```

By inspecting the data, we see that data frames with even numbers of observations result in an exact 50% sample, whereas data frames with odd numbers of observations are slightly above or below 50%.

### A Base R solution

We can also solve the problem with Base R. This approach uses the three variables in the original post, product type, offer, and inventory to split the data into subgroups based on the combinations of values for these variables, take a random sample from each subset, and combine the result into a single data frame.

First, we set the seed for the random number generator and build a data frame containing 10,000 rows of products, where 50% of the products are on offer, and 70% are in inventory.

```
set.seed(1053807)
df <- data.frame(
     productType = rep(c("Bed","Mouse","Table","Cellphone","Laptop","Car","Chair","Blanket",
                          "Sofa","Bicycle"),1000),
     offer = ifelse(runif(10000) > .5,"Y","N"),
     inventory = ifelse(runif(10000) > .3,"Y","N"),
     price = rnorm(10000,200,10)
)
```

Since we want to separately sample each combination of product, offer, and inventory, we create a combined split variable, and then use it to split the data.

```
splitvar <- paste(df$productType,df$offer,df$inventory,sep="-")

dfList <- split(df,splitvar)
```

Given the input data frame parameters of 10 products, 2 levels of offer (Y / N), and 2 levels of inventory (Y / N), this creates a `dfList` object that is a list of 40 data frames, each with varying numbers of observations.

We then use `lapply()` to randomly select about 50% of each data frame, using the number of rows for each data frame to drive the `sample()` function.

```
sampledDataList <- lapply(dfList,function(x){
     x[sample(nrow(x),size = round(.5 * nrow(x))),]
})
```

At this point the `sampledDataList` object is a list of 40 data frames, each of which has approximately 50% of the rows as the original list.

To create the final data frame, we use `do.call()` as follows.

```
sampledData <- do.call(rbind,sampledDataList)
```

When we check the number of observations in the resulting data frame, we see that it is approximately 50% of the original data size (10,000).

```
> # this should be approximately 5,000 rows
> nrow(sampledData)
[1] 5001
```

We can further verify that each data frame is approximately a 50% sample with the following code.

```
# verify sample percentage by stratum
stratum <- names(sampledDataList)
OriginalCount <- sapply(dfList,nrow)
SampledCount <- sapply(sampledDataList,nrow)
SamplePct <- round(SampledCount / OriginalCount * 100,2)
head(data.frame(stratum,OriginalCount,SampledCount,SamplePct,row.names = NULL),10)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(data.frame(stratum,OriginalCount,SampledCount,SamplePct,row.names = NULL),10)
       stratum OriginalCount SampledCount SamplePct
1      Bed-N-N           161           80     49.69
2      Bed-N-Y           371          186     50.13
3      Bed-Y-N           132           66     50.00
4      Bed-Y-Y           336          168     50.00
5  Bicycle-N-N           154           77     50.00
6  Bicycle-N-Y           349          174     49.86
7  Bicycle-Y-N           147           74     50.34
8  Bicycle-Y-Y           350          175     50.00
9  Blanket-N-N           134           67     50.00
10 Blanket-N-Y           349          174     49.86
```

As was the case with the `dplyr` solution, we see that strata with odd numbers of rows either sample one more or one less than an exact 50% of the original data.